# How to combine two columns of factors into one column without changing the factor levels into number

Tags: r

I am trying to find a way to combine two columns of factors into one column without changing the factor levels into numbers. For instance, consider the following two data.frame datasets

```
  dataset 1                       dataset 2
  Number  Student                 Number Student
       1    Chris                      1    Matt
       2    Sarah                      2   Keith
```

I am trying to take "student" column from the dataset1 and the "student" column from the dataset2, and make one big student column containing the names "Chris", "Sarah", "Matt", and "Keith"

I tried:

```
  student.list<-c(dataset1[,2],dataset2[,2])
  student.list
```

However, this doesn't work since the names turns into numbers with c() function. I want my list to preserve the names of students (i.e. without converting them into numbers). I also tried cbind(), but gives same problem as c()...

Thank you

Comment: If you create the function `c.factor <- function(..., recursive=TRUE) unlist(list(...), recursive=recursive)`, as given in the manual, factor concatenation by `c()` should then give a `factor` and not their internal `integer` codes.

Comment: Since R 4.1.0: *Using c() to combine a factor with other factors now gives a factor, an ordered factor when combining ordered factors with identical levels.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`factors` *are* numbers that happen to have labels. When you combine factors, you generally are combining their numeric values. This can often trip a person up.

If you want their labels, you must coerce them to strings, using `as.character`

```
 student.list <- c( as.character(dataset1[,2]) ,
                    as.character(dataset2[,2])  )
```

If you want to get that back to factors, wrap it all in `as.factor` *(can be all in one line, or split into two lines for easier reading)*

```
 student.list <- c(as.character(dataset1[,2]),as.character(dataset2[,2]))
 student.list <- as.factor(student.list)
```

Comment: I would've guessed that there was a "combine" function that does this for you in base...? EDIT: guess not, though the `gdata` package changes `c` for factors to have the OP's expected behavior.

Comment: @Frank you could use `gdata::combine`, but then you'd have to filter out what you need. And that still wouldn't help in learning how to handle factors in `R`

Comment: How about the performance of these operations? Do as.character and as.factor force the creation of entirely new columns? Or is R smart  and just juggles a bit with the data type administration?

Answer (score 5):

There is `interaction()` function in the base R package. 
There is also `strata()` function in the `survival` package.

Answer (score 2):

The `data.table` package, which extends the functionality of data frames in some very useful ways, will combine factors automatically when you use the `rbindlist` function.  Plus, if your two data sets are large, it will usually combine them more quickly.

```
library(data.table)

# Example data:
# (If you already have data frames, you can convert them using `as.data.table(dataframename)`)
dataset1<-data.table(Number=1:2,Student=as.factor(c("Chris","Sarah")))
dataset2<-data.table(Number=1:2,Student=as.factor(c("Matt","Keith")))


# Combine the two data sets:
# (It's not necessary to convert factors to characters)
rbindlist(list(dataset1,dataset2))
#   Number Student
#1:      1   Chris
#2:      2   Sarah
#3:      1    Matt
#4:      2   Keith
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this easily with `fct_c()` from the `forcats` package.

```
dataset1 <- data.frame(Number = c(1,2), Student = factor(c('Chris','Sarah')))
dataset2 <- data.frame(Number = c(1,2), Student = factor(c('Matt','Keith')))

library(forcats)
fct_c(list(dataset1[ ,2], dataset2[ ,2]))

# [1] Chris Sarah Matt  Keith
# Levels: Chris Sarah Keith Matt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you factors are inside of data frames then you can combine them this way using `rbind`:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(x=factor(c('a','b')))
> df2 <- data.frame(x=factor(c('c','d')))
> rbind(df1,df2)
  x
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

Comment: but that will return a data.frame, not a vector, and not to mention if you are combing two columns as in the OP (ie, without `drop=FALSE`) then the end result will still be the integer representation