# How can I combine two columns in R when the variable are not numerical?

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-columns

I have two columns in a data table in `R`. One is race and the other is ethnicity. I would like to combine these two columns to make one new column labeled R/E. However, I am having difficulty combining the variables because I want to replace the variable of one column from another in certain circumstances without replacing the variables for the entire column.

Let's say I have these two columns.

```
Ethnicity <- c("Hispanic or Latino", "Not Hispanic or Latino", "Not Hispanic or Latino", "Neither", "Neither")

Race <- c("Neither", "Asian", "Neither", "Asian", "Neither")
```

Desired Column (R/E): `c("Hispanic or Latino", "Asian", "Not Hispanic or Latino", "Asian", "Neither")`

I want to create one column where I can combine these variables accordingly.
I have tried to use ifelse but I am not sure of the correct syntax.

I basically want to say:
If ethnicity = "Hispanic or Latino" -> R/E = "Hispanic or Latino",
If ethnicity = "Unknown" or ethnicity = "Not Hispanic or Latino", then check "Race"

Can I use `ifelse` to do this? Or is there another function I can use to achieve this?

I am not sure where to go from

```
NewData$R/E <-ifelse(NewData$Etn<= Hispanic or Latino, "Hispanic or Latino",  ifelse(NewData$Etn<= Neither,
```

Comment: Look up the ifelse() function.

Comment: This seems to already be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201773/how-to-combine-two-columns-of-factors-into-one-column-without-changing-the-facto)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine two columns of factors into one column without changing the factor levels into number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201773/how-to-combine-two-columns-of-factors-into-one-column-without-changing-the-facto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve the desired column(R/E). I have named it as R_E for sake of readability(R editor does not accept R/E as variable name).

```r
Ethnicity <- c("Hispanic or Latino", "Not Hispanic or Latino", "Not Hispanic or Latino", "Neither", "Neither")

Race <- c("Neither", "Asian", "Neither", "Asian", "Neither")

R_E <- c(paste0(Ethnicity,", ", Race))
```

For 2nd part of your question. Can you please elaborate what information you want to filter and what input value?

Answer (score 1):

If the 2 vectors are the same length (for example, if they're 2 columns from a data.frame), you can just use a properly formatted `ifelse` statement:

```
ifelse(Race == 'Neither', Ethnicity, Race)

[1] "Hispanic or Latino"     "Asian"                 
[3] "Not Hispanic or Latino" "Asian"                 
[5] "Neither"
```

Though, be careful: if the vectors aren't the same length, the shorter one will be repeated to make it the same length, causing strange results like this:

```
ifelse(Race == 'Neither', c("A","B","C"), Race)

[1] "A"     "Asian" "C"     "Asian" "B"
```